# vue.c[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions

Tags: vue.js

i got this warning :

> vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

I attached my code below is in function but i got same error, what I did wrong.

vue.js

```
data: function() {
  return {
    message: 'Some Message'
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code via https://codesandbox.io/s/vue ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: i solved my issue in my component , it comes from specific component ,check patiently in  your each component that you registered in main.js.use only function in your data .

Comment: I understand the error itself, but all my codes (except new Vue(...)) uses function, after compared all files, I found I made a mistake:    <code> render: function(h, ctx) {return (ctx.children[0]);}   </code>,          here, "h(ctx.children[0])"  is a wrong calling, it should be "ctx.children[0]";  but this error message is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above data format is correct but my error comes from specific component but vue warned me from parent component so i get confused.

solution , just check patiently each component of data format shoud be in function   ,That you registered in main.js

```
 data() {
    return {
      message: 'some message',
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'some message',
    };
  },
```

Comment: Why do you think changing to this other format is going to fix the problem? Is it possible that dropping this code into the file where the other function is failing will cause this to fail in the same manner because we don't have enough contextual information?